# How to serialize a library class to Protobuf with kotlinx.serialization?

Tags: kotlin, protocol-buffers, kotlinx.serialization

How to serialize a library class to Protobuf with [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization)? Since it's non-editable, I can't add `@SerialId` annotations to its properties as instructed in [runtime_usage.md#protobuf](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/runtime_usage.md#protobuf). If I write my own external serializer as in [custom_serializers.md](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/custom_serializers.md), it doesn't tell me how to specify the `SerialId`s for Protobuf serialization.

For example, I am trying to serialize a `java.math.BigDecimal`, storing its `unscaledValue` as `bytes` and its `scale` as `sint32`. It's easy to do it with the original Protobuf Java library, but I am wondering how to do it with [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization).

Answer (score 0):

You can use contextual serialization for class you have no control over. For example define your serializer like this (json in my case but you get the idea)

```kotlin
val kxJson = Json {
    serializersModule = SerializersModule {
        contextual(java.math.BigDecimal::class, BigDecimalKSerializer)
    }
}
```

And then implement your `BigDecimalKSerializer`. In classes where you use `BigDecimal` you should annotate field with `@Contextual`.

More details are [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#contextual-serialization).